# Update Target Audience for WebParts being added to a SPWeb

Tags: web-part, event-receivers

I have the following requirements:
All WebParts which are added to certain SPWebs (these are generally projectsites, so there are a lot of them and new ones are created regularly) should be updated regarding their Target Audience.

Is there a possibility to update an added WebPart, just like for instance one can do with EventReceivers for added Lists? As far as I have seen there is no such EventReceiver so I wonder how I could achieve such behaviour.
Any help is appreciated.